# OData SSIS Connection Issue

Tags: ssis, odata, etl, microsoft-dynamics, axapta

when i try to connect odata using SSIS i get the error of  401 Unauthorized error (system).
i have tried to connect with basic authentication and i am 100% sure that my credientials are correct. because i can connect from excel and powerbi. also when i open url of odata in my browser i can see the data.

also i tried other connection ways like Microsoft Dynamics CRM Online or Microsoft Dynamics AX Online i get an error message of 400 Bad Request.

i am sure that my entity names doesnt start with numbers.

Comment: Have you checked if it is a TLS 1.2 issue? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/integration-services/data-flow/odata-source?view=sql-server-ver15#supported-data-types

Comment: yes, but it did not help.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

finally i am able to know how to do this right now.

first of all we should use Microsoft Dynamics AX Online connection way.
and we have to be sure about our account does not need multifactor authentication of office 365.

you can create a user just for this integration and you are going to use that user crediantials to connect using Microsoft Dynamics AX Online connection type. After you enter the information of user and click test connection a pop-up screen must be opened automatically and once more you should again login microsoft with that integration user.

trick is that user must have permissions on both azure and dynamics 365 and should not be affected multifactor authentication.

i hope it will be helpful for someone because i learnt this by paying money :))